# Storing simple data in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've set up this simple form that allows you to enter your personal details and have them stored in a DB, but it does not work.

Form HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="test" action="store.php" method="post">
Voornaam: <input type="text" name="first_name"> <br>
Achternaam: <input type="text" name="last_name"> <br>
E-Mail: <input type="text" name="e-mail"> <br>
Telefoon: <input type="text" name="phone"> <br>
Adres: <input type="text" name="address"> <br>
Postcode: <input type="text" name="postal_code"> <br>
Stad: <input type="text" name="city"> <br>
Provincie: <input type="text" name="province"> <br>
Land: <input type="text" name="country"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Verzenden">
</form>
<body>
</html>
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
/*Database test.
© 2013 Sydcul. All rights reserved.*/

//Please change the following settings:
/*Your database host*/ $host = "localhost";
/*Your database user*/ $user = "root";
/*Your database password*/ $password = "";

//Please don't change the following:
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);

mysql_select_db("contact", $connection);

$debug = "INSERT INTO data (first_name, last_name, e-mail, phone, address, postal_code, city, province, country)
VALUES ('" . $_POST["first_name"] . "', '" . $_POST["last_name"] . "', '" . $_POST["e-mail"] . "', '" . $_POST["phone"] . "', '" . $_POST["address"] . "', '" . $_POST["postal_code"] . "', '" . $_POST["city"] . "', '" . $_POST["province"] . "', '" . $_POST["country"] . "')";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (first_name, last_name, e-mail, phone, address, postal_code, city, province, country)
VALUES ('" . $_POST["first_name"] . "', '" . $_POST["last_name"] . "', '" . $_POST["e-mail"] . "', '" . $_POST["phone"] . "', '" . $_POST["address"] . "', '" . $_POST["postal_code"] . "', '" . $_POST["city"] . "', '" . $_POST["province"] . "', '" . $_POST["country"] . "')");

echo $debug;

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

I believe I got it to work once, but that was with only the first name.
I think it is something really obvious I don't see, so please take some time to look at it and help me.

I put the debug stuff in for debugging, it shows me this:

```
INSERT INTO data (first_name, last_name, e-mail, phone, address, postal_code, city, province, country) VALUES ('John', 'Johnson', 'john@johnson.com', '1234567890', 'Street 1', '1234 AB', 'City', 'Province', 'Country')
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: When debugging MySQL, always look to see if `mysql_query` failed, and if it gave an error.  `$q = mysql_query('...');  if(!$q){ die(mysql_error()); }` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: Thanks for notifying me about the fact it's deprecated. I don't like using old code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your email field `e-mail` has to be surrounded by the backtick character (`` ` ``) such that your final query should be

```
INSERT INTO data (first_name, last_name, `e-mail`, phone, address, postal_code, city, province, country) VALUES ('John', 'Johnson', 'john@johnson.com', '1234567890', 'Street 1', '1234 AB', 'City', 'Province', 'Country')
```